# Program does send mail in eclipse, but doesn't when jarred

Tags: java

My program is supposed to automatically send mails. This does work perfectly in eclipse, but when I jar it (obviously packaging the required library into the jar to make it a runnable jar), it somehow doesn't send the mail. So of course, my first thought was that there would be something wrong about my extracted libraries, but I've double-checked every option.

Is there any other reason why this could occur?

```
    // sets SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
    properties.put("mail.user", userName);
    properties.put("mail.password", password);

    // creates a new session with an authenticator
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

This is where it goes wrong at `"Message msg = new MimeMessage(session)"`

Comment: @Stultuske Yes sorry I was busy with updating the post :$ Posted it a little too early sorry!

Comment: where are the properties values (e.g.: hostname, port) stored? in the Jar itself?

Comment: Have you debuged your code?

Comment: they are stored in the same file, but authentication is set to false, and that could not really be the problem (or it should neither work in eclipse)

Comment: @Jens yes jens, I did, that's why I can clearly say that the problem is at that line "Message msg = new MimeMessage(session)

Comment: What kind of Problem?

Comment: Well, Session uses "properties" and "auth", so there's a problem with one of them. Note that auth (authenticator) is part of an external library. The properties should not be the problem (I think) because it shouldnt work in eclipse then

Comment: edit: I think the actual issue is properties. I've removed the authenticator lines , still doesnt work. Program still stops at Message msg = new MimeMessage(session)

Comment: Are you running jar on the same PC where you use eclipse?

Comment: Where do you get the values for the properties `mail.smtp.host` and `mail.smtp.port`?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException as you can read those are set to variables host and port. host = is ip and port is 25 (for outgoing mails)

Comment: Yeah but where do you set these variables? Do you set them directly in your code or do you read them from a file?

Comment: directly in my code